# if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $c$, then $c$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and, in fact, the only one.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality

> if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $c$, then $c$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and, in fact, the only one.

I already proved what concerns that $c$ is a limit point, nonetheless I'm stuck with the uniqueness part.

Suppose there exists $c'$ diferent from $c$ such that $c'$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, then, by particularizing the definition of limit point for $c$ and the one of limit for $c$, I have

- $|a_{n'}-c'|\leq\epsilon$ for $n'\geq N$
- $|a_{n'}-c|\leq\epsilon$ for said $n'$

Here's where I get stuck.
I suspect I'm supposed to apply triangle inequality or inverse triangle inequality somehow to make $|c-c'|\leq 0$ happen, but I'm struggling with how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $|c-c'| \leq 2\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$ implies that $c=c'$.

Comment: What definition are you working with for a "limit point"?

Comment: Terence Tao's: For every ε>0, for every N∈ℤ|N>=1, there exists n>=n such that |a_n-c|<=ε

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For notational simplicity, I'll establish the following:

- We are working in $\mathbb{R}$ with the distance $d$ between $x,y$ being $d(x,y) := |x-y|$
- $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is your sequence
- $x$ is its established limit point
- $y \ne x$ is a hypothetical extra limit point
- By definition, $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - x| < \varepsilon$
- By definition, $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - y| < \varepsilon$

Now, consider: what is the distance between your limit points?

$$|x-y| = |x-a_n+a_n-y| \le |a_n-x| + |a_n-y|$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $n \ge \max \{M,N\}$ (for the corresponding $M,N$ per the definition of limit point). Then the above will have

$$|x-y| < 2 \varepsilon$$

Since we can do this for all $\varepsilon > 0$, in the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$,

$$|x-y| \le 0 \implies |x-y| = 0 \implies x = y$$

a contradiction.

Comment: Could you further clarify on the "Since we can do this for all ε>0, in the limit ε→0, |x−y|≤0" part? I'm taking this Analysis course for the first time, so I don't get what you did there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget it, I already understood. Thanks!